# Pytest: How to display failed assertion only once, not twice

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

I run pytest via PyCharm, and execute a single test:

```
/home/guettli/projects/lala-env/bin/python /snap/pycharm-professional/230/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --target test_models.py::test_address_is_complete
Testing started at 11:53 ...
Launching pytest with arguments test_models.py::test_address_is_complete in /home/guettli/projects/lala-env/src/lala/lala/tests

============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.2.0, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /home/guettli/projects/lala-env/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
django: settings: mysite.settings (from ini)
rootdir: /home/guettli/projects/lala-env/src/lala, configfile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-4.1.0
collecting ... collected 1 item

test_models.py::test_address_is_complete Creating test database for alias 'default' ('test_lala')...
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: allauth, colorfield, debug_toolbar, google, messages, staticfiles
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, lala, sessions, sites, socialaccount
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0001_initial... OK
  Applying account.0002_email_max_length... OK
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying auth.0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length... OK
  Applying lala.0001_initial... OK
  Applying lala.0002_offer_price... OK
  Applying lala.0003_order_amount... OK
  Applying lala.0004_auto_20201215_2043... OK
  Applying lala.0005_auto_20201229_2148... OK
  Applying lala.0006_auto_20201229_2150... OK
  Applying lala.0007_auto_20210117_1632... OK
  Applying lala.0008_auto_20210117_1632... OK
  Applying lala.0009_add_address... OK
  Applying lala.0010_auto_20210117_2102... OK
  Applying lala.0011_auto_20210119_1909... OK
  Applying lala.0012_allergen_short... OK
  Applying lala.0013_auto_20210119_1914... OK
  Applying lala.0014_auto_20210120_0734... OK
  Applying lala.0015_auto_20210120_0752... OK
  Applying lala.0016_auto_20210120_1923... OK
  Applying lala.0017_allergenuser... OK
  Applying lala.0018_address_place... OK
  Applying lala.0019_auto_20210126_2027... OK
  Applying lala.0020_auto_20210126_2027... OK
  Applying lala.0021_recurringoffer_days... OK
  Applying lala.0022_auto_20210126_2129... OK
  Applying lala.0023_auto_20210201_2056... OK
  Applying lala.0024_globalconfig_navbar_title... OK
  Applying lala.0025_activationstate... OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0001_initial... OK
  Applying sites.0002_alter_domain_unique... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0001_initial... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0002_token_max_lengths... OK
  Applying socialaccount.0003_extra_data_default_dict... OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default' ('test_lala')...
FAILED
lala/tests/test_models.py:18 (test_address_is_complete)
user = <User: Dr. Foo>

    def test_address_is_complete(user):
        address = user.address
>       assert address.is_complete
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <Address: Address object (1)>.is_complete

test_models.py:21: AssertionError


Assertion failed


Assertion failed


=================================== FAILURES ===================================
___________________________ test_address_is_complete ___________________________

user = <User: Dr. Foo>

    def test_address_is_complete(user):
        address = user.address
>       assert address.is_complete
E       assert False
E        +  where False = <Address: Address object (1)>.is_complete

test_models.py:21: AssertionError
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_models.py::test_address_is_complete - assert False
============================== 1 failed in 2.88s ===============================

Process finished with exit code 1


Assertion failed

Assertion failed
```

Why does the exception gets displayed twice?

Comment: This is just how the PyCharm test runner displays the result for different levels. If you run the same outside of PyCharm, this won't occur. Inside of PyCharm, just select the test in question to see the output related to the test itself - it should show the assert only once. If you select the test module or test class instead, it additionally shows the output of the whole test module/test class.